# UISegmented Control with a UITabBar on the bottom

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using a segmented control as suggested by Marc M here: [How do I use a UISegmentedControl to switch views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047114/how-do-i-use-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-switch-views)

I also have a tabbar on the bottom that I would still need to use regardless of what segment I am on.

[image: a busy cat]

How to I get the segmented control to switch XIB files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should follow the answer provided by @Rayfleck.

To setup a segmented control,

1. Setup a view controller for Media.
2. Setup a UISegmentedControl and assign labels Teaching and Worship
3. Create two view for each Teaching and worship (respectively), and have them ready with your data.
4. Use the link you had provided in your question and check the example on the usage for -

   ```
    (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(id)sender
   ```

   and link them to the two views.

Comment: I saw the code you directed me to, but how do I tell create the subviews in code? I have built them in interface builder, but I don't know how to name them.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was making things much harder than they are. That cleared everything up!

Answer (score 0):

Teachings and Worship would both be sub-views of the Media view.  Devotions, About, Connect, Live Service would each their own views, completely independent of the Media view and it's sub-views.

Comment: How would I do that with a segmented control?

Comment: Whatever VC has the segmented control will also have a view.  Add Teachings and Worship as sub-views of that view, and toggle between them as per the link in your original question.