# How to use a segmented control in the toolbar to switch views?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, selector, uisegmentedcontrol

As it has been asked many times, I am trying to switch views by using a segmented control correctly. I cannot just hide/display because the views are too complicated.

I have gotten it to work using [this solution](http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047114/how-do-i-use-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-switch-views/3666693#3666693), but this places the segmented control in the title bar. **I would like to palce it on the bottom, in a toolbar.**

I have tried hooking it up via IB and declaring each subviews control, but no luck. I think it has something to do with the  `@selector` section.

Can someone please shed some light on this for me?

Comment: check out this: - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11220027/846372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIBarButtonItem *item = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl] autorelease];`

// if you are in a navigation controller:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];
```

// else, created a UIToolBar called toolBar at the bottom of the view and...

```
toolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];
```