# How to make a button , iOS

Tags: ios, button, view, picker

I am trying to make a button for the user where he will be able to choose between 5 different options. I have in mind something like an one line button where one option will be preselected and when the user presses the button the 5 options would be displayed for the user to choose. In the objects library the closest i can find to that is the picker view , but its too big for my screen and it displays all the options , as i only want one to be displayed in the beginning and when the user hits the button all the options so that he can pick a different one if he likes. Is there a button like this on xcode that i am missing or should i customize a picker view or something?

Comment: Go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047114/how-do-i-use-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-switch-views

Comment: Spend some time familiarizing yourself with the objects available from Interface Building.  The UISegmentedControl (shown below) sounds like exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be a segmented control, but that gets too large when you have many options.

I'd recommend to use a customized UITextfield with a UIPickerView as inputView. So the user can only select the text from the picker, not through the keyboard.

It's also possible to do that with a UIButton, that would require to subclass UIButton.

Here is a tutorial on how to achieve this: http://nomtek.com/tips-for-developers/working-with-pickers/

Comment: +1 because I'm guilty of updating my answer with an example of your answer :-/

Comment: Thank you very much the tutorial is exceptional

Answer (score 2):

How about a UISegmentedControl with 5 buttons?

[image]

phix mentioned the UITextField/UIPicker Combo like this

[image]

Comment: I thought of that too BUT my options are cities and not numbers...So they cant fit in the screen like this.