# Ios swift container view and segmented control switch views

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uicontainerview

I have segmented control, and container view, now how can i make 2 views and segmented control needs to switch that 2 views in container view?

I can't find any tutorial for swift or obj c.

Comment: How far did you try ? http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047114/how-do-i-use-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-switch-views

Comment: I saw this, but i need with container view.. i  think its better solution?

Comment: see my second link it's another solution.Or you can do anything you want to switch 2 view in segmentSwitch event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, go into the container view's View Controller and make sure your two views are variables, either via Interface Builder or Code.
Let's say you called them `view1` and `view2`.

In your `viewDidLoad()` write (swift):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "segmentedControlTapped:", name: "SCTapped", object: nil)
```

Then, make a new function like this:

```
func segmentedControlTapped(notif: NSNotification){
    let index = notif.userInfo["index"] as Int

    if index == 0{
        view1.hidden = false
        view2.hidden = true
    }
    else if index == 1{
        view1.hidden = true
        view2.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Then, in the View Controller housing your Segmented Control, hook up an IBAction (if using IB) to the Control's `ValueChanged` action or use code.

The IBAction func should look like this:

```
@IBAction func tapped(sender: UISegmentedControl){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("SCTapped", object: nil, userInfo: ["index": sender.selectedSegmentIndex])
}
```

What this should do, is when the SC is tapped, it will call the tapped function, which tells the NSNotificationCenter to post a message. This should be received by the VC with the views in it and segmentedControlTapped() should be called, and it will switch your views.

Comment: Can't make that `adInfoViewController.hidden = false` to work `does not have a member named 'hidden'`, and on top of file i put `var adInfoViewController = AdInfoViewController()` didn't do anything from storyboard. Do i need something else to do?

Comment: Yes, you can't hide a UIViewController because it is not the same as a UIView. You need to make the two UIViews you want to hide first. Sorry, I assumed you already had them.

Comment: But can i make this with 2 viewcontrollers, so it can be separated, for better control? Maybe with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`? If you have code for that?

Comment: Ok, with 2 view controllers instead of two UIViews, it is actually much easier. All you need is 2 container views in the same place, and when you tap the segmented control, you hide one and show the other, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks.. this works :D just one more question, how can i pass data to containers controller? I have variable `id` in contianer controller view, so how to set that variable from parent? Then i will check if didSet..

Comment: This seems to be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279105/access-container-view-controller-from-parent-ios