# TabBar inside view of TabBar

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to put a tabBar inside of another tabBar. I want a tabBar on the bottom of the screen and then another tabBar that inside that view that will be able to render different components. A good example would be the Yik Yak app with the 'Nearby' and 'My Herd' tabBar and then the 'new' and 'hot' tabBar within those two views.

[Yik Yak Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKV8q.png)

Comment: As in Picture two components were placed in navigator and a two control tabbar right!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a custom [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html).  You can [customize it's appearance](http://smnh.me/customizing-appearance-of-uisegmentedcontrol/), and [switch the visible view based on the selected segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047114/how-do-i-use-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-switch-views)!

Of course, you can also just use regular buttons to switch the visible view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-native-scrollable-tab-view for this.